# Mysql is it quicker to have search/filters statements in the select or where clause?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have an advanced MySQL search that is running a radius search based on lat and lon.
Last time I built such a system there were many issues with the speed of the query.
I have been reading around and I noticed that some people will have it in the select.

`SELECT *, (6271 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(long) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM carpark HAVING distance < 15 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10";`

Or it is also possible to run it in the where clause.

`Where ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(".$lat.") ) * COS( RADIANS( grt32sg32u_PostCodeData.lat ) ) 
   * COS( RADIANS(PostCodeData.lon) - RADIANS(".$lon.")) + SIN(RADIANS(".$lat.")) 
   * SIN( RADIANS(PostCodeData.lat)))) <= 15";`

So which one is quicker? Are they both the same speed or is there a difference?
Are there other ways I can optimise this query?

Comment: Perhaps the people who put it in the SELECT and WHERE clauses had a requirement to display the distance, and the people who put it only in the WHERE clause did not need to display it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Geo expert, but if we assume you have a large-ish database, you're doing a lot of math on records that will ultimately have a distance > 15.

I don't know which (clause in the `SELECT` or clause in the `WHERE`) is faster, but I think you'll see a much bigger performance gain from limiting the results returned by either clause

Can you simplify this into two queries?  Instead of computing a radius, how about (pseudo code below)

```
where PostCodeData.lat between $lat - radius and $lat + radius
```

This should run pretty quickly - no math on the rows, and lat and lon are probably indexed.

You can then run your radius query on the results of this one.  Hopefully instead of looking at thousands of rows you'll be looking at less than a dozen.

It is much much faster to search for points in a square than to search for points in a circle.  The trick here is to narrow your search to the smallest enclosing square then use radius (if you really need it) to eliminate points in the corners.

On an unrelated but important note, please review your code for [possible SQL Injection issues](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Yes I have read about this method and I had planned to run with it. My lat and lon are not indexed. I'll need to organise this. I was having trouble running them as float values.

Comment: Indexing lat & lon will probably make a big difference.

Comment: Just did it. Using varchar. I believe that was a major mistake I made last time.

Comment: @Shane float values in MySQL have rounding problems you should consider to use numeric data type